# Silverlight Asnyc method not executed

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I'm working on a Silverlight site, which requires me to read from an XML file. This file is located server-side. The user cannot select one of their own files.

Silverlight cannot read files in its own folders. Only via OpenFileDialog can Silverlight read a file, but this file is uploaded by the user and considered to be a stream. As I said before, the file I need to read is not uploaded, but resides in the same map as the XAP file. Here's a screenshot of my VS2010 solution explorer:

[image]

So, as you can see, the file is included. Do note: this is not intended to become a finished product, it's just something I'm working on to get to know Silverlight better.

I got the code I am using from this blog: http://blogs.silverlight.net/blogs/msnow/archive/2009/02/10/silverlight-tip-of-the-day-93-reading-xml-with-silverlight.aspx

I've pasted the entire class in a pastebin page, as it is a little much to paste here(but not too much to give it a read :P ): http://pastebin.com/eEMGGxsB

The method tied to the DownloadStringCompleted EventHandler is never executed. Nor will the Debugger step in to it.

Can anyone tell me what it is that's going on here?

Answer (score 0):

The code that is making the call to DownloadStringAsync looks reasonable.  Whenever you have a problem like this the first port of call is [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/).  Use that to determine exactly what conversation the client is actually having with the server.

One immediate fail I see in the code for the completed event is you are accessing the `e.Result` before testing whether `e.Error` has a value.  Accessing the `Result` when `Error` contains an exception will cause that exception to be thrown.  Hence in your code if you haven't put your break point right at the top of the event handler it will never be reached if there is some problem with the download.

Another issue with the code is that your `displaySnippet` method is run before the completed event and therefore will be trying to access an as yet unpopulated codeList.  Don't forget this is asynchronous code, you will want to execute `displaySnippet` at the end of the completed routine.

Comment: about the e.Result being accessed before e.Error: I did that on purpose to see if the variable I assigned it to would still be NULL after the function was supposed to happen. This was added after some initial testing. As for the second issue: I am not aware of how I can set up my code to wait for the async function to be completed.

Comment: @WebDevHobo:  How about just calling it in the Completed code rather than in the constructor?  So your first step is install fiddler and examine what is actually happening between client and server.  I can't see any reason why completed would not fire.